# Aggregating dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, date, aggregate-functions

I have a 2-column table named `Assignment`. The table contains assignment of Person (`nvarchar(20)`) and Day (`date`), like here:

```
Person      Day
------------------
John    2011-05-23
John    2011-05-24
John    2011-05-25
John    2011-05-27
John    2011-05-28
John    2011-05-29
Anna    2011-05-02
Anna    2011-05-03
Anna    2011-05-06
```

I need to extract the date ranges when there is a sequence of adjacent days. The output should be a single string value for every row:

```
------------------
John    2011-05-23 - 2011-05-25
John    2011-05-27 - 2011-05-29
Anna    2011-05-02 - 2011-05-03
Anna    2011-05-06 - 2011-05-06
```

I tried grouping and then

```
   CAST(min(Day) AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST(max(Day) AS VARCHAR)
```

but it does not work correctly.

Any advice is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: This answer can be adapted to fit your table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099279/need-help-finding-the-correct-t-sql-query/6099433#6099433

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson Thank you that worked, please write your comment as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: From the above mentioned answer... ;With Cte as(
select *, DATEDIFF(D, 0, A.Day) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Person ORDER BY A.Day) Grp from Assignment A
)
Select Person, MIN(Day), MAX(Day) from Cte
group by Person, Grp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @T table(Person nvarchar(20), [Day] date)

insert into @T values
('John',    '2011-05-23'),
('John',    '2011-05-24'),
('John',    '2011-05-25'),
('John',    '2011-05-27'),
('John',    '2011-05-28'),
('John',    '2011-05-29'),
('Anna',    '2011-05-02'),
('Anna',    '2011-05-03'),
('Anna',    '2011-05-06')


;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *,
        DATEDIFF(DAY,0,[Day])-
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY [Day]) AS Grp
FROM @T  
)
SELECT Person, 
       MIN([Day]) AS DateFrom, 
       MAX([Day]) AS DateTo  
FROM cte 
GROUP BY Person, Grp
```

Comment: +1; nice answer, anyway why I can see at this post above your name `community wiki` ?

Comment: @daemon_x – Community wiki post does not give reputation to the poster and since this answer is a direct copy of Martin's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099279/need-help-finding-the-correct-t-sql-query/6099433#6099433 I thought is was the right thing to do.

Comment: @Mikael - so you mark this anwser as a community wiki somehow ? I don't know about this magic. You flagged yourself ?

Comment: @daemon_x – Yes I did. It is a checkbox down to the right of the screen when you answer questions. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: @Mikael - I see; I overlooked the check box even if it's directly in front of me :) Thanks for the info.

Comment: @daemon_x: From the page linked by Mikael: `Once a post is made community wiki […], that mode cannot be reversed.` Just wanted to highlight it for you to make sure you wouldn't overlook it. :)